# How to create a clustered stacked column chart in Google Sheets?

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

[This is the type of chart I want to create, months on x-axis.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYyoO.png)
Found instructions on how to do this in excel (see "DoubleColumn": https://ufile.io/nu18b) but cannot replicate this in Sheets.
[Someone figured out how to do this in the "Vizualization API.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/X6Mad7NCCPU)" Hope thats helps.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible via user interface alone. There is no option to create a "grouped stacked column chart". 

You might want to do the grouping yourself, by introducing a "dummy" column of zeros, and labeling the values creatively.

If you want a script solution, please post what you have already tried and didn't work.